# error: invalid use of non-static data member 'NNetwork::NH' in c++ (also to NH and NI)

Tags: c++

```
class NNetwork
{
private:

    int NI, NH, NO;

    double W1[NH][NI];
    double W2[NO][NH];

public:

// some method to insert values to NI,NH,NI

}
```

Even if I initialize these 3 variable with values without using method to insert values, still I get error when I use the variables as indexes for arrays (W1, W2)

Comment: class NNetwork
{
private:
  
    int NI, NH, NO;
    NI=2;
    NH=2;
    NO=1;
    double W1[NH][NI];
    double W2[NO][NH];
}
Now it says NI does not name a type

Comment: You can't write arbitrary code outside of functions. Initialization code traditionally goes in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you think that piece of code would work, bottom line is you can't declare arrays of non-constants in C++. Especially uninitialized ones.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, variable length arrays are not allowed. `W1` and `W2` needs to know both of its dimensions at *compile time*.

Use

`std::vector<std::vector<double> > W1, W2 ;`

if you want to initialize row and col at runtime.

```
class NNetwork
{
    public:
    NNetwork(size_t ni, size_t nh, size_t no ): NI(ni),NH(nh),NO(no)
    {  }

    private: 
    const size_t NI, NH, NO; 

    vector<vector<double> > W1, W2;  
};
```

For compile time you can use templates or `std::array`<sub>*C++11*</sub> like :

```
template<size_t NH, size_t NI, size_t NO>
class NNetwork
{
private:
    double W1[NH][NI]; // or std::array< std::array< double, NH>, NI > W1;
    double W2[NO][NH];
};
```

Then,

```
NNetwork< 1,2,3> W1 ;
NNetwork< 7,8,9> W2 ;
```